# Inserting a char at particular index of line(s) in a file using awk or sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

Is there a Linux way (awk, sed, grep etc) to insert a character at particular index in each line in a file?

For example below is the content of file.txt

```
0067011990999991950051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+00001+99999999999
0043011990999991950051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+00221+99999999999
```

I want to insert a comma at given indexes (say 15,19,88 and 93) of each line in file.txt, so that the resultant would like :

```
006701199099999,1950,051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+,00001,+99999999999
004301199099999,1950,051512004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203201N00671220001CN9999999N9+,00221,+99999999999
```

Comment: can use dd with conv=notrunc

Comment: @amdixon Thanks for suggestion. I'm newbie in stackoverflow. Will keep in mind the formatting next time.

Comment: Maybe this pure `bash` solution can help: `while read -r line; do echo "${line:0:15},${line:15:4},${line:19:69},${line:88:5},${line:93}"; done < file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simpliest in sed

```
sed 's/\(.\{93\}\)/&,/;s/\(.\{88\}\)/&,/;s/\(.\{19\}\)/&,/;s/\(.\{15\}\)/&,/' YourFile
```

order is important or you need to keep in mind added character for next change

you could do it at once but need some interpretation

```
sed 's/\(.\{15\}\)\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{69\}\)\(.\{5\}\)/\1,\2,\3,\4/' YourFile
```

Comment: You do not need the `()` if you are using `&`

Comment: Thanks! It works. You save me a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: @123 No, it stay from complex version that i do first. You are right,

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '$l = $_;
          substr $l, $_, 0, "," for reverse 15, 19, 88, 93;
          print $l' < input > output
```

I used [reverse](http://p3rl.org/reverse), because you need to start from right - otherwise, after each insertion, all remaining indices must be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/./&,/93;s/./&,/88;s/./&,/19;s/./&,/15' file
```